# Loading images in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I want to load images using webpack to front-end(react)

---

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    filename: `[name].bundle.js`,
    // `chunkFilename` provides a template for naming code-split bundles (optional)
    chunkFilename: `[name].bundle.js`

  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
         new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
            }
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template:'src/index.html'})

  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: ['babel-loader'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    },{
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "url-loader",
                    options: {
                        limit: 25000,
                    },
                },
            },{
            test: /(\.css)$/, 
            use: ['style-loader', 
                     'css-loader']
        },  {test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i, use: ["file-loader"]}
    ]
  }
};
```

---

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    <img src="resourses/css/images/headerImage.jpg"/>
        <script src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="main.bundle.js"></script>
    <img src="resourses/css/images/headerImage.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**my package.json**

```
"webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.11.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.1"
   "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
```

This is image of same html but, I have removed stylesheet link for this question.

[image]

I have set file-loader in webpack but still no image is showing in source when I see in the browser. Moreover I have used img tag.It is also not giving me any result. If you required any more data then I will edit the post and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you images will only be processed by webpack if you include them, somewhere in your dependency tree, i.e `'./src/index'` or any other file that index includes. If you put on index.html webpack won't process.

Comment: @ PlayMa256 image folder is in  .`/src` folder

Comment: but are you explicitly importing them? `import myLogo from './logo.png'`?

Comment: @ PlayMa256  no, I am just importing them using img tag. Like `<img src="resourses/css/images/headerImage.jpg"/>`

Comment: Yeah, you must import them as i stated above, otherwise webpack won't know about your images.

Comment: @ PlayMa256 I just did that after you told me to do. But now it is showing error saying `module not found`.

Comment: post you code, after your changes on a github or somewhere like that, so people can better see.